# Moving from Selenium IDE to what?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

I have been given the following job from my boss:

- three years ago a former employee created selenium tests for our project and committed them via eclipse
- now I have to update the tests due to the fact that the software has changed through time.
- I created new IDE tests, instead of editing the old ones.
- I have committed them through CVS in the project folder and I access them via a browser (selenium has some folder in the project)
- when I run these tests via IDE, they run fine, but when I run them via the TEstRUnner that is in the old selenium installation, there are a lot of errors.

Should I install new version of Selenium in the project folder and what should it be?

Or should I just run the tests from IDE instead? (I read somewhere that TestRunner will be deprecated)

How are tests made in IDE run through Web Driver?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Selenium Builder](http://sebuilder.github.io/se-builder/)?  It supports migrating existing scripts, works well with [Sauce Labs](http://saucelabs.com) and there is also a Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Builder+Plugin) available.

Answer (score 0):

Tests built using Selenium IDE are built using Selenium RC (1.0), and selenium WebDriver is the foundation of Selenium 2.0. Selenium has a [migration document](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_migrating_from_rc_to_webdriver.jsp) for this transition. In moving to Web Driver, you might be required to code the tests yourself, rather than using the point and click Selenium IDE.

Additionally, there is a hybrid approach for using Selenium RC code on Selenium Web Driver: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#alternative-back-ends-mixing-webdriver-and-rc-technologies

In order to run the Web Driver tests, you will need to have a selenium server or local browser to execute these tests. Some examples are [SauceLabs](https://saucelabs.com/), [Selenium Grid](http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/), a standalone [Selenium Server](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#running-standalone-selenium-server-for-use-with-remotedrivers), or I believe you allow [Web Driver to directly control the browser](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#how-does-webdriver-drive-the-browser-compared-to-selenium-rc) on the computer executing the code.

Comment: so can you tell me what do you suggest that I do now? I am kinda lost, I've been working with Selenium for a day all in all.

Comment: If you're used to just using selenium IDE and running it that way, then for the short term I would probably get a bit more familiar with that. If you are very comfortable with writing code, then start looking at a hybrid migration to Web Driver running it locally on a machine with a browser.

Comment: this means I can discard their previous way of running tests by Test Runner and create and run all the test with IDE (they are not that complex, so IDE is perfect for the job)? in the mean time I will learn RC and Web DRiver but it will take time.